# Chroma Subsampling with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, output, mp4, subsampling

I want to create an .mp4 output. But it doesn't work...

I'm using ffmpeg. My input video is a raw video and I want to have an raw video .mp4 at the end.

My code that i use:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.y4m -c:v rawvideo -vf format=yuv420p output.y4m
```

Can anyone help me out? :)

Comment: "raw video .mp4 at the end" ? do you mean raw video .y4m ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is: `ffmpeg.exe -i input.y4m -pix_fmt yuv420p output.y4m`

Test sample:

Build synthetic video `y4m` file in YUV444 format:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=rate=10:size=160x120 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv444p input1.y4m
```

Convert from YUV444 to YUV420:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.y4m -pix_fmt yuv420p output1.y4m
```

---

---

---

You can also create AVI raw video:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.y4m -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p output1.avi
```

But you can't create raw mp4 video.
Following code: `ffmpeg -i input1.y4m -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p output1.mp4` returns error message:

> [mp4 @ 00000140d77eb9c0] Could not find tag for codec rawvideo in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
>   Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
>   Error initializing output stream 0:0 --

There is an error because mp4 container doesn't support raw video format.